# « Chasser » vs « pourchasser »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, anglais, étymologie, comparaison-de-langues

Pendant que je recherchais l'étymologie du substantif (pas le verbe) anglais *purchase*, j'ai recouru à Etymonline qui mentionne le verbe *pourchasser*:

> [Etymonline for **purchase (v.)**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=purchase&allowed_in_frame=0): ... (11c., Modern French *pourchasser*) from *pur*- "*forth*" (possibly used here as an `intensive prefix`; see [pur-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pur-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + Old French *chacier* "run after, to hunt, chase" (see [chase](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chase&allowed_in_frame=0) (v.)). . ...

Je ne savais pas que *pourchasser* existait aussi, dont le sens n'est pas celui du verbe *purchase* en anglais moderne (mais peut-être que *purchase* connotait ceci, jadis ???).

Quels sont les liens entre « chasser » et « pourchasser » ? En quoi diffèrent-ils ?

Ci-dessus, Etymonline estime qu'il se peut que le préfixe ***pour-*** soit un « `intensive prefix` ».
Du coup, ceci signifie-t-il que *pourchasser* est plus violent que *chasser* ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le verbe « *to purchase* » ne contient pas l'idée de *pourchasser*, mais le nom la contenait (voir *OED1*, [*purchase*](http://archive.org/stream/oed07arch#page/n1625/mode/1up), subst.) en anglais; tous ces sens sont maintenant éteints. *Chasser* et ce qui est relatif à la chasse comme telle, c'est début 12ème en français avec l'idée de capter/poursuivre/poursuite des animaux pour les tuer - [*chacier*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/chacier) (aussi [*porchacier*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/previous/dictionnaire-godefroy/285/6/porchacier)), ou dans sa forme picarde *cachier* (qu'on emprûntera pour former [*to catch*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=catch&allowed_in_frame=0)).

De plus, dans le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (dir. A. Rey, *ed. Le Robert*), on indique que pourchasser est un « *[doublet](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublet_lexical) intensif de chasser* »; d'abord employé en forme pronominale comme *s'évertuer à*; le sens propre *avec acharnement* provient du 12-13ème, tandis qu'on a *chercher à obtenir*, au figuré; *pourchasseur*, lui, est rare. Même si des sens étaient communs entre les deux mots à l'origine (par exemple, chasser/pourchasser en droit, ou la chasse/[pourchasse](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pourchas) amoureuse), bien des sens sont disparus ou ont glissé vers « poursuivre » par exemple, et donc c'est bien moins le cas aujourd'hui à l'évidence (comparer [*chasser*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chasser)([2](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/chasser?idf=dmfXdXpcYccf;str=0)), [*pourchasser*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pourchasser)([2](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/pourchasser?idf=dmfXgXrmXpjcg;str=0)) au *TLFi* et *DMF*). L'*acharnement*, tel qu'[expliqué](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13606), constitue l'élément déterminant du verbe pourchasser. Reste que *chasser* est plus [fréquent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chasse%2Cpourchasse%2Cporchacier%2Cpourchacier%2Cpourchasser%2Cchasser%2Cpourchas%2Cpurchas%2Cpurchase%2Cchacier%2Cpourchaz%2Cprochasser&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchasse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpourchasse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cporchacier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpourchacier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpourchasser%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchasser%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpourchas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpurchas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpurchase%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchacier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpourchaz%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprochasser%3B%2Cc0); *pourchasser*, peut-être plus [intense](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pourchasser%20*_ADV%2Cchasser%20*_ADV%2Cpourchasser%20sans%20*%2Cchasser%20sans%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cpourchasser%20*_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpourchasser%20mal_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourchasser%20tout_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourchasser%20partout_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourchasser%20impitoyablement_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourchasser%20plus_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cchasser%20*_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bchasser%20enti%C3%A8rement_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20tout_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20hors_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20compl%C3%A8tement_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20loin_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20honteusement_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20plus_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20d%C3%A9finitivement_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20ainsi_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20encore_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cpourchasser%20sans%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpourchasser%20sans%20rel%C3%A2che%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourchasser%20sans%20r%C3%A9pit%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourchasser%20sans%20tr%C3%AAve%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpourchasser%20sans%20piti%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cchasser%20sans%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bchasser%20sans%20permis%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20sans%20retour%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20sans%20piti%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20sans%20%C3%AAtre%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20sans%20chiens%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20sans%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20sans%20cesse%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20sans%20permission%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20sans%20peine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchasser%20sans%20chien%3B%2Cc0). On peut aussi jeter un coup d’œil aux constructions impliquant un verbe à l'infinitif et [*pour*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pour)/[por](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/por) (à cause de, dans le but, avec finalité ou destination, par comparaison; ajoutant davantage la [précision](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=pro) que l'intensité, à mon avis) ou à l'ancienne forme du déverbal, [*porchas*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/porchas).

Answer (score 6):

En effet, "pourchasser" indique une intensité supérieure à "chasser".

**chasser** décrit un acte plutôt passif mais néanmoins méthodique

> chasser le gibier

dans la pratique: *chasser n'importe quel animal qui croiserait la route du chasseur*

Tandis que **pourchasser** indique un but précis, une détermination certaine et une pratique systématique :

> le régime pourchasse les opposants

*indique une traque systématique*

Answer (score 1):

Chasser quelqu'un : Le faire fuir, l'obliger à partir. C'est un peu agressif mais cela sert généralement pour "défendre son territoire", on chasse un intrus, quelqu'un qu'on ne veut plus voir.

Pourchasser quelqu'un : C'est d'après moi beaucoup plus agressif. Cela veut dire traquer quelqu'un, lui coller au baskets, ne pas le lâcher et souvent c'est utilisé dans le sens d'une course poursuite (le bandit s'enfuit et la police le pourchasse).

Answer (score 0):

"Chasser" veut dire pratiquer la chasse ou expulser quelque chose ou quelqu'un.
Exemple: Chasser le chevreuil, chasser ses idées noires, chasser un intrus de chez soi.

"Pourchasser" veut aussi dire persécuter. 
Exemple: "Ce régime totalitaire pourchasse sans répit ses opposants"